# a large number of/ large numbers of, What's the difference?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

> Tests are hard to solve for **large number** of users.

Checking the similar usage of such expression, I think there is something wrong with the sentence. What's the best and correct? a large number OR large numbers OR even something else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are both correct:

> Tests are hard to solve for **a large number** of users.
>
> Tests are hard to solve for **large numbers** of users.

The second sentence has a slightly more general connotation, like "users in general", whereas the first probably implies users of a specific application.